# Why is resizing a WPF window jerky in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I just upgraded a Windows 7 system to Windows 10. When I run my Visual Studio solutions (C# and WPF, VS 2015 & 2017) and use the mouse to resize a window, it hesitates very badly or stops resizing until the mouse is released, then the window resizes to the position of the mouse. If I open a form in the solution such that it is not extending outside an underlying WPF window, then the resizing is fairly normal. But as soon as any edge of the window is dragged outside the boundary of the underlying WPF window, it has the same hesitation/start/stop behavior. All other apps and windows resize smoothly. I did not have this behavior when this system was running Windows 7.

Dragging the entire WPF window around on the screen is completely smooth.

I have updated the video drivers with no change in behavior.

Why would these WPF apps have this resize behavior in Windows 10?

Comment: Probably this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/573655/wpf-mouse-capture-issue-windows-10-1903.html. It is a bug in Windows 10 1903.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens nailed it. This was being caused by a mouse capture bug present in Windows 10. When I disabled tablet support using the code mentioned in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/573655/wpf-mouse-capture-issue-windows-10-1903.html the WPF window resizing started to behave normally.

Answer (score -1):

Because your running the app in Debug mode. Is caching turned on? Is it nearing memory limit? I have Win10 64bit and do not experience any screen redraw problems. Try shutting down some apps, then launch VS. Failing that update VS to the latest version and make sure your using the latest .Net framework.